# How to do an OR with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I havent been able to figure out how to do something equivalent to this SQL statement in Objectify

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable.attribute = 'X' OR myTable.attribute = 'Y'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use 'OR' criteria in App Engine. Each query is executed as a single index scan, and that's not possible with disjunctions. Instead, you need to execute each query separately, and intersect the results.

I'm not sure how this relates to text search, however.

Comment: does that mean i have to do that intersection in java?

Comment: not shure, but isnt that too slow, is that scalable? Do you know a good way to do it?

Comment: @pictureyournews Yes, but every SQL database does the same thing in the backend - there's no way to efficiently satisfy a query with disjunctions. Workarounds depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My algorithm in SQL was originaly this: there is a Table KeyWords with (int, varchar), where int represents a foreign key for an object and varchar represents a keywords for that object, for example (1,dog),(1,animal), (2, people) means that the object with id 1 will be searched with the words dog or animal and the object with key 2 will only be searched with people. So when a user enters a search text, like SEARCH:= big dog, it would search all ocurrences that match at least one of the words in the search text, and then order by the number of ocurrences that have matched. How could I do this?

Comment: @pictureyournews This would require a disjunction and multiple index scans in SQL, too. Do you really want a disjunction, though? When I search for "socket wrench", I don't want results that contain socket _or_ wrench, I want results that contain both.